# Group Categories for axis in Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

It is possible to have groups in amcharts axis?

Check the example in highcharts : [example](http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of... it's not an official feature but you can fake it.

You can have a graph for the label, with a valueField which is always zero.
You'll also need to offset the category axis so the labels don't hide each other.

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/XY2cD/

```
// each data provider has a label property
dataProvider : 
  [{ ... ,
    "label": 0 
    }, ... ],
// the first graph in each 'cluster' is for the label
"graphs": [    
  {
    "type": "column",
    "fillAlphas": 0, // hide this column
    "lineAlpha": 0, // hide this column
    "title": "my sub group name",
    "valueField": "label", // this is the field that's always zero
    "showAllValueLabels": true, // even though the field is zero - the label will be shown
    "labelText": "\n[[title]]" // start this with a newline so it's below the axis
  }, ... ],
"categoryAxis": {
    "labelOffset": 15
}
```

(not my fiddle, I just found it online)